# Values are not being deleted in a table in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello im trying to delete which ever value is selected in a drop down list.

I cant seem to understand what is going on

I have 2 pages 1 with my connection and functions to view the table in a drop down (which works) and a delete function (which doesn't seem to work) and another to call the function in and to delete which ever value is selected.

**connection.php**

```
<?php

//Connect to the database
function getSQLConnection() {
$mysqlConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=isad235_100000', "root", "");

return $mysqlConnection;
}

//Get all results from members table
function getResults($tablename) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tablename;

$mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

$ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
return $ResultSet;
}

//Delete results from members table
function deleteValue($id) {
$sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id = '$id'";

$mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

$ResultSetting = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
return $ResultSetting;
}

   ?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
   include_once 'connection.php';
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Add</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1> Delete a Member from the Members Table. </h1>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method='post'>   
        Delete Member:
        <select name='members' value='members'id="Mmembers">       
            <?php
            $results = getResults('members');
            if ($results) {
                foreach ($results as $row) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['member_id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
                }
            }
            else
                echo '<option value="0"0"> No Data</option>';
            ?>

        </select>

        <input type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"/>
        <br/> 
        <br/>
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['members'])) {


        $ResultSetting = deleteValue(($_POST['members']));
    }
    ?>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <form action='index.php' method='GET'>
        Go Back: 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Return"/>
    </form>

    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work means you get error ? Or query doesn't delete the row ?
Put this in the beginning of your script:
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: Is form data sended to this function? Seems like you just send data to index.php and then nothing happens from there?

Comment: Its okay, i got it to work! It was a slight error in naming part of the function :)

Comment: $sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE member_id = '$id'"; <- is member_id a string or an integer in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and don't see any errors with it.  Make sure the id column on your 'members' table is called 'member_id'.  If there is a discrepancy in the name then the values for the option elements wouldn't be set.  Also, the value you just deleted would still appear after the initial page submit.  If you reload the page after the submit, you'll see the value has disappeared.